How do I handle Dynamic Binding to Xaml in C#
I'm trying to update the binding on my xaml program dynamically with a launch from my viewmodel.cs
For some reason I cant get the binding to show on my label.content in my cs:
Every time I run, either I get a default value that is set in the ViewModel Constructor but doesn't update dynamically or when I comment out the value in the constructor, it remains blank.
Xaml:
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Label x:Name="lblStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,10" Content="{Binding UpdateStatusTxt}"/>

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel; 

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    _viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "UpdateStatusTxt")
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblStatus.Content = _viewModel.UpdateStatusTxt);
        }
    };
    DataContext = _viewModel;
}

ViewModel:

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            //StatusMessage = new RelayCommand(UpdateStatusTxt);
            // Initialize CurrentMasterProducts
            CurrentMasterProducts = new List<clsProductData>();
            CurrentMasterAliases = new List<clsProductAlias>();
            ImportMasterProducts = new List<clsProductAlias>();
            ImportNAData = new List<clsProductData>();
            ImportFullData = new List<clsProductData>();
            ImportNotFoundData = new List<clsProductData>();
            ImportNativeData = new List<clsProductData>();
            ImportExpandedUPCData = new List<clsProductData>();
            ImportAliasFoundData = new List<clsProductData>();
            //UpdateStatusTxt = "Idle...";

        }

        private string _updateStatusTxt;
        public string UpdateStatusTxt
        {
            get
            {
                return _updateStatusTxt;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_updateStatusTxt != value)
                {
                    _updateStatusTxt = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged();
                    // OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UpdateStatusTxt)); //notify the binding 
                }
            }
            
        }

        public static bool LoadMasterProducts(string FileToUse, MainWindowViewModel _viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                _viewModel.UpdateStatusTxt = "Importing Master Products...";
                _viewModel.WaitTask();
                using (var tmpFileReader = new StreamReader(FileToUse))
                {
                    // Skip the header row
                    tmpFileReader.ReadLine();


Please note I've tried it with the OnPropertyChanged() that is commented in the example as well as the uncommented line.
I've tried various incarnations of code as shown above with commented out code.

In your XAML, remove the Window.DataContext, you are already setting the DataContext in your MainWindow's constructor, Also, remove the event handler for _viewModel in MainWindow's constructor. The binding will handle all of that. If you uncomment the //UpdateStatusTxt = "Idle..."; line in the View Model constructor, your label should display Idle... when the window opens.

When you assign a value explicitly to the Label.Content property then you are overwriting the Binding. The Binding is gone, hence no updates. Initialize the property via the view model (or the binding source in general).

Turns out it was a combo of both.  the explicitly assigning to Label.Content was overwriting and I fixed up my code to make it run smoother.
I also added Async processing since the program was processing too quickly to update the UI correctly.

Your MainWindow's constructor doesn't need the following:
_viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "UpdateStatusTxt")
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblStatus.Content = _viewModel.UpdateStatusTxt);
    }
};

You are trying to manually update the label's Content when UpdateStatusTxt changes; the Label's Binding mechanism handles this automatically.
You just need the following in your constructor:
private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel; 

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;
    
}

In your XAML, you don't need to specify a Window.DataContext, you just did that in the constructor so remove the Window.DataContext block.
As far as UpdateStatusTxt is concerned, your View Model looks fine. When UpdateStatusTxt changes, anything that has a binding to it will update.
You do not show code that updates it though. It looks like LoadMasterProducts does that but you don't explain when that gets called. Furthermore, you are passing a MainWindowViewModel as a parameter but the code is already in that object:
_viewModel.UpdateStatusTxt = "Importing Master Products...";

This should simply be:
UpdateStatusTxt = "Importing Master Products...";

Unless you are somehow using a different MainWindowViewModel instance, you should also remove the parameter altogether:
public static bool LoadMasterProducts(string FileToUse)
{
    try
    {
        UpdateStatusTxt = "Importing Master Products...";

        using (var tmpFileReader = new StreamReader(FileToUse))
        {
            // Skip the header row
            tmpFileReader.ReadLine();

If you uncomment the //UpdateStatusTxt = "Idle..."; line in the View Model constructor, your label should display Idle... when the window opens, until you change the value of UpdateStatusTxt.

Thanks for the comment:
The UpdateStatusTxt update i'm updating in is here
_viewModel.UpdateStatusTxt = "Importing Master Products...";
That is suppose to go to the binding on the xaml to update a status label on the bottom of the ui.

@RobertZantarra yes but the code you posted doesn't call LoadMasterProducts

@Etinette Laneville
Apologies : This is launched from xaml.cs
private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (OKToContinue() && MainWindowViewModel.LoadMasterProducts(MasterProductsFilePath, _viewModel) &&
MainWindowViewModel.LoadMasterAliases(AliasProdctsFilePath, _viewModel) &&
MainWindowViewModel.LoadImportSheetProducts(ImportSheetFilePath, _viewModel))
{
lblStatus.Content = "Scrubbing...";
_viewModel.ExpandImportUPCProducts(_viewModel.ImportNativeData);
}

@RobertZantarra you should make this code part of your view model, as a relay command, and bind the button's Command to it.

@Etinette Laneville
Ok, will set that up in and do some testing.  will comment here on results. Thanks

@RobertZantarra update your question with the updates you make so we can see the changes you have made. In general your code should be in your View Model instead of in the code-behind file (xaml.cs).
